# Best way to validate for bsonnull in a bson document in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

My sample document looks like this.

```
 sampledoc = { "name" : "shan",
                   "address" : {
                                "add1" : "",
                                "add2": null
                                }
                  }
```

if i need to get the value of add2 = >

```
var valueR = sampledoc["address"].asbsondocument["add2"].asstring;
```

So if value is there it is giving perfect.
If address is bsonNull in mongodb , that time it is giving cast error.

So i m using condition like

```
if(!sampledoc["address"].IsBsonNUll && !sampledoc["address"].asbsondocument["add2"].IsBsonNUll )
{
//do that stuff
}
```

this is fine.
but if the nested document is upto 3-4 level then these look's bad.

Is there any other way to validate as whole like that **add2 field is null or not in a line as straight without validating like i did in that IF Condition separetly** ?

Comment: I'd assume you'd do some caching and some nested blocks, just like you'd do if you hadn't kept them as `BsonDocuments`. While you could write an extension method to test a path, it wouldn't be a natural API as you'd still need to get the deepest reference to the containing subdocument to access a field like `add2` in your example. In your example, it could sometimes return a `null` or a `BsonDocument`, which would make the deep inspection messier.

Answer (score 0):

You should typically be converting the document into a c# object. you would still need to check for null on the inner object but it would look cleaner.